# How to get all form data for a POST request using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, post, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a website developed with ASP.NET Ajax with Excel VBA. I'm using the Microsoft HTML Object Library and the Microsoft XML, v6.0 library. What I would like to do is to get in a table all the items in the second text box when I select an item in the first text box.

When you select an item in the first text box automatically the items on the second text box are loaded. So first I make a `GET` request to the [website](https://www.smv.gob.pe/Frm_EVCP?data=5A959494701B26421F184C081CACF55BFA328E8EBC), then I scrape all the elements with the class `aspNetHidden`. I add two elements to the `POST` string that doesnt' appear in the first scrape: `ctl00$ctl18`, `__ASYNCPOST`, with their respective values. I also added the value for the first text box `ctl00$MainContent$cboDenominacionSocial`.

```vb
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
    ' Declare variables
    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim urlMF As String

    '
    urlMF = "https://www.smv.gob.pe/Frm_EVCP?data=5A959494701B26421F184C081CACF55BFA328E8EBC"

    '

    '
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", urlMF, False
    'xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3842.0 Safari/537.36"
    'xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xmlhttp.send

    Dim bodySMV As New HTMLDocument
    bodySMV.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText

    Dim topicsSMV As Object
    Dim topicElem As Object

    Set topicsSMV = bodySMV.getElementsByClassName("aspNetHidden")

    Dim postReq As String
    postReq = ""

    i = 1
    For Each topic In topicsSMV
        Set topicElem = topic.getElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each dataTopic In topicElem
            Cells(i, 1) = dataTopic.Name
            Cells(i, 2) = dataTopic.Value
            temp = dataTopic.Name & "=" & dataTopic.Value
            If i = 1 Then postReq = "ctl00%24ctl18=ctl00%24MainContent%24UpdatePanel1%7Cctl00%24MainContent%24cboDenominacionSocial"
            If i > 1 Then postReq = postReq & Chr(38) & temp
            i = i + 1
        Next dataTopic
    Next topic
    postReq = postReq & "ctl00%24MainContent%24cboDenominacionSocial=156429&__ASYNCPOST=true&"
    Cells(i, 1).Value = postReq

    xmlhttp.Open "POST", urlMF, False
    xmlhttp.send postReq
    bodySMV.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText

'
End Sub
```

I'd like to get all the list of possible elements from the second text box, depending on the selection of the first box. What am I missing in my `POST` request?

Comment: I tried replicating and the viewstate and/or eventvalidation don't seem to match up for my attempt.